# How does connectedStreams work in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm following the example in the official doc of Flink to try to understand how `connectedStreams` work. Here is the example: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/learn-flink/etl.html#connected-streams

```
public class StreamingJob {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyFlink.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    DataStream<String> control = env.fromElements("DROP", "IGNORE").keyBy(x -> x);
    DataStream<String> streamOfWords = env.fromElements("Apache", "DROP", "Flink", "IGNORE").keyBy(x -> x);
  
    control
        .connect(datastreamOfWords)
        .flatMap(new ControlFunction())
        .print();

    env.execute();
}

public static class ControlFunction extends RichCoFlatMapFunction<String, String, String> {
    private ValueState<Boolean> blocked;
      
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        blocked = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("blocked", Boolean.class));
    }
      
    @Override
    public void flatMap1(String control_value, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
        blocked.update(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
      
    @Override
    public void flatMap2(String data_value, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
        if (blocked.value() == null) {
            out.collect(data_value);
        }
    }
}
}
```

As my understanding, the first parameter `control_value` of the method `flatMap1` should be the elements of the control stream, and the first parameter `data_value` of the method `flatMap2` should be the elements of the `streamOfWords`.

However, when I try to print them, I always get the empty values.

Here is my changes:

```
@Override
public void flatMap1(String control_value, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("flatMap1111111: ", control_value);
}

@Override
public void flatMap2(String data_value, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("flatMap2222222: ", data_value);
}
```

After executing this job, in the log file `./log/flink-root-taskexecutor-0-localhost.localdomain.log`, I can see that

```
2020-07-25 02:40:30,152 INFO  myflink.StreamingJob                                          - flatMap1111111:
2020-07-25 02:40:30,153 INFO  myflink.StreamingJob                                          - flatMap1111111:
2020-07-25 02:40:30,174 INFO  myflink.StreamingJob                                          - flatMap2222222:
2020-07-25 02:40:30,174 INFO  myflink.StreamingJob                                          - flatMap2222222:
2020-07-25 02:40:30,174 INFO  myflink.StreamingJob                                          - flatMap2222222:
2020-07-25 02:40:30,174 INFO  myflink.StreamingJob                                          - flatMap2222222:
```

As you see, they are all empty.

Did I do something wrong or misunderstand how `connectedStreams` work?

Comment: Does your modified job (the version with logging) still have a print sink attached to the job? If not, the ControlFunction won't be executed. If you simply add the logging to the original code, it should work.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes. The code `control.connect(streamOfWords).flatMap(new ControlFunction()).print(); env.execute("StreamingJob");` is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seek for the file `*.out`, not the `*.log`. The expected output is:

```
2020-07-24 16:18:21,083 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend     - Initializing heap keyed state backend with stream factory.
3> Apache
4> Flink
2020-07-24 16:18:21,126 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task
```

Use `out.collect()` on `flatMap2`, or `print()` won't work in this case. Here is the working version, which produces the output above. The first stream `"Apache", "DROP", "Flink", "IGNORE"` is consumed and filtered by the shared variable `blocked`. The second stream `"DROP", "IGNORE"` modified the shared variable `blocked`.

```
package org.sense.flink.examples.stream.tests;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.co.RichCoFlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;

public class ConnectedStreamTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStream<String> control = env.fromElements("DROP", "IGNORE").keyBy(x -> x);
        DataStream<String> streamOfWords = env.fromElements("Apache", "DROP", "Flink", "IGNORE").keyBy(x -> x);

        control
                .connect(streamOfWords)
                .flatMap(new ControlFunction())
                .print();

        env.execute();
    }

    private static class ControlFunction extends RichCoFlatMapFunction<String, String, String> {
        private ValueState<Boolean> blocked;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration config) {
            blocked = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("blocked", Boolean.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void flatMap1(String control_value, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
            blocked.update(Boolean.TRUE);
        }

        @Override
        public void flatMap2(String data_value, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
            if (blocked.value() == null) {
                out.collect(data_value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```